# AWK : Replace comma in quoted string with underscore and remove quotes

Tags: unix, awk

Data:

1.txt

```
-1,"AAA",aaa@ymail
-10,"B ,BB","b, bb@ymail"
-7,C,c@gmail
```

I want to
1.Remove comma in quoted string with underscore 
2.Remove quotes also after that

I am using below :

```
awk -F'"' -v OFS='' '{ for (i=2; i<=NF; i+=2) gsub("[,]", "_", $i) } 1' 1.txt > 2.txt
```

output:(note that " in first line ["AAA"] is not removed because of there is no comma

```
-1,"AAA",aaa@ymail
-10,"B ,BB",b_ bb@ymail
-7,C,c@gmail
```

So additionally I use

```
awk -F'"' -v OFS='' '{ for (i=1; i<=NF; i+=1) } 1' 2.txt > 3.txt

-1,AAA,aaa@ymail
-10,"B ,BB",b_ bb@ymail
-7,C,c@gmail
```

Please suggest a better way of doing the above

Comment: The simplest solution is to stop thinking that comma-separated data is the only valid form of delimited data. Awk and unix in general assume that data separator chars will appear only as data separators, and not as a data value. Consider exporting your data with tabs or '|' chars. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add an `$1=$1` command, the output will be split and remerged, so the field separator will not appear in the output.

```
$ awk -F'"' -v OFS='' '{ for (i=2; i<=NF; i+=2) gsub("[,]", "_", $i);$1=$1 } 1' file
-1,AAA,aaa@ymail
-10,B _BB,b_ bb@ymail
-7,C,c@gmail
```

Comment: Thanks user000001 that worked. Thanks for explanation

Answer (score 2):

I'd select a language with a proper CSV parser. For example, ruby:

```
ruby -r csv -ne '
  row = CSV.parse_line($_).collect {|f| f.gsub(/,/,"_")}
  puts CSV.generate_line(row)
' <<END
-1,"AAA",aaa@ymail
-10,"B ,BB","b, bb@ymail"
-7,C,c@gmail
END
```

```
-1,AAA,aaa@ymail
-10,B _BB,b_ bb@ymail
-7,C,c@gmail
```